# Ruby String Parsing with Double Quotes

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parsing

In my ruby on rails project I want to create a string that includes an array which is stringified. For example:

```
irb(main):047:0> array = ["a", "b", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Now I want to create a string with the array so that the array is stringified with double quotes around each element. For example:

```
"my array is '["a","b","c"]'"
```

I have tried and got:

```
irb(main):051:0> "my array is [#{array.map { |item| %Q["#{item}"] }.join(", ")}]"
=> "my array is [\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

Note that the `\` is not desired and I want to get rid of them. So I tried

```
irb(main):056:0> "my array is [#{array.map { |item| %Q["#{item}"] }.join(", ")}]".gsub('\\','')
=> "my array is [\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

Note that the `\` are still present.

How do I get it to

```
"my array is '["a","b","c"]'"
```

Or is it not possible to do?
Thanks!

Comment: `=> "my array is [\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"` is already correct; IRB is only "displaying" backslashes for representing this String literal

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using string interpolation, ruby will have to escape the double quotes inside the string. Otherwise it will be creating different strings separated by all those quotes.

You can have the same result with this code:

```rb
"my array is #{array}"
=> "my array is [\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

Be aware that those backslashes are only internal.

So, basically, you were doing it right, just don't need the whole mapping stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display them with the double quotes you can do this as well:

```
>> my_array = ["a", "b", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> puts('My array is \'["%s", "%s", "%s"]\'' % my_array)
My array is '["a", "b", "c"]'
=> nil # this is the return of `puts`
>> puts %q|"My array is '["%s", "%s", and "%s"]'"| % my_array
=> "My array is '["a", "b", and "c"]'"
```

So you already "get it to" what you want, but in showing this in context of code, the escapes need to happen, or it would indicate the end of the string, but in the example above, we are working with output, rather than the representation of the object in the context of Ruby.

I also did not do the double quotes around the string as output, as it is probably not what is intended.  (Unless it is really meant to be a quote.)

Comment: Edited to show we can do this without using escapes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about double quotes, but if your ultimate goal is to create a string that demonstrates how you created your array, you could also consider defining your array a little differently:

```
array = %w[a,b,c]

"my array is '%w#{array.to_s.gsub("\"", "")}'"

=>"my array is '%w[a,b,c]'"
```